# How to get the results into a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm new to C#. How would I display the SQL in Razor view?

```
// GET: /ReportData
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"select * from ProjectManagement as p 
            join Implementation as i on p.JobNumber = i.JobNumber 
            join Divisions as d on i.Division = d.Division 
            where p.ProjectStatus = 'Active'"

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // process result
                    reader.GetValue(0);
                    reader.GetValue(1);
                    reader.GetValue(2);
                    reader.GetValue(3);
                    reader.GetValue(4);
                    reader.GetValue(5);
                }

            }
        }
    }         

    return View();
}
```

I understand this is up to the reader object but after that I have no clue on how to proceed. Just need the gist...

Comment: First use dummy data to be displayed in the view. Then you will understand how to get results from the sql and display those results

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into the Entity Framework and get into modeling. This question requires a lot to answer it.

Microsoft's EF (Entity Framework) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx
or of course use stackoverflow and look for entity framework and view model with razor.

The above answer would assume you are using this and would not work for the old method of looping through the database as you are doing. This is really not much of an answer, but you have some research to do on the Entity Framework or another ORM (Object Relational Mapper) and that should get you going.

```
// GET: /ReportData
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<DataHolder> data = new List<DataHolder>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx"))
    {

        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"select * from ProjectManagement as p 
            join Implementation as i on p.JobNumber = i.JobNumber 
            join Divisions as d on i.Division = d.Division 
            where p.ProjectStatus = 'Active'"

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {                  
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   data.Add( new DataHolder {
                      Item1 = reader.GetValue(0),
                      Item2 = reader.GetValue(1)
                   });
                    // process result
                    //reader.GetValue(0);
                    //reader.GetValue(1);
                    //reader.GetValue(2);
                    //reader.GetValue(3);
                    //reader.GetValue(4);
                    //reader.GetValue(5);
                }

            }
        }
    }         

    return View(data);
}


public class DataHolder {
  public string Item1 { get; set; }
  public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view.cshtml

```
@model List<DataHolder>

@foreach(var a in Model) {
  <p>@a.Item1 @a.Item2</p>
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use an ORM here. However, it would be advisable.

Comment: jumpingcode is correct. I just read my response and it does seem that I made it sound like you have to use an ORM. The code I posted does roughly show how to hook up the data with your current code without using an ORM.